# aws cognito guest user login with java

Tags: java, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook, amazon-cognito-triggers

Is there any way by which we can allow guest user i.e. who is not a registered user in cognito to login. We are using java. Also how can we allow a user to login with other identification providers such as Facebook, Google etc.

Thanks